# How to create the login app using webservice in livecode?

Tags: web-services, livecode

I am building a LiveCode application but I am newer in livecode. Can anyone suggest me how to create login app using the webservice api in livecode or any tutorial link that I can reference? Thank a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to build a *client* in LiveCode (like an app on a phone, or a browser), or a *server*? So do you want to allow the user to log into an existing service using your app, or will your LiveCode app be running on your server and provide the actual service?

Comment: I want to build mobile app and allow the user to log into existing web application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no web services API built into LiveCode as such, but it is very simple to access existing RESTful APIs. You can submit GET requests using the form `put URL "http://apihost.com/document.html?name=value"`. You can submit PUT requests using the LiveCode `post` command: `post argList to URL "http://apihost.com/document.html"`.
If you are interested in a tutorial, see this one I put together at http://livecode.byu.edu/internet/webServicesIntro.php